# Left join 3 tables returning results for every match in right table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fairly straightforward, I have 3 tables i need to join. The DB (MSSQL) should have 1 record in the first two (p and u) tables, and then multiple records in the 3rd table (a).

I only want it to return a match from the first table (is that not a left outer join?) regardless if there is a match in the second table, but if there is display that match, and then if there is a match in the 3rd table (most situations there will be multiple matches) but to only use the first match when the column appt_date is ordered DESC (giving me the most recent appointment date)

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.ln, p.fn, p.sex,
u.ud1_id, u.ud2_id, a.date, a.time

FROM  person p LEFT OUTER JOIN person_defined u
ON p.person_id = u.person_id LEFT OUTER JOIN appointments a
ON p.person_id = a.person_id
where p.home_phone = '123456789'
ORDER BY a.appt_date DESC
```

Comment: It is not clear what problem with your query you have. Is it because the row duplication of the appointments relationship? What are the wrong behavior that you are getting?

Comment: You call p and u first tables, which one is "first"? Is there always a row on p and u?

Comment: use `max(COLUMN)` in your select statement on whatever column you want to return the most recent date from.

Comment: There is always a row on p and u, if there is no row on p and u there will be no rows on a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `OUTER APPLY` operator here to find the most recent appointment for each person. This is much easier than using the combination of the `GROUP BY` and `ROW_NUMBER()` operators.

```
SELECT 
p.person_id, p.ln, p.fn, p.sex,
u.ud1_id, u.ud2_id, 
pa.date, pa.time
FROM person p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_defined u ON p.person_id = u.person_id 
OUTER APPLY
(
    select top 1 a.date, a.time
    from appointments a
    where a.person_id = p.person_id
    order by a.appt_date desc
) pa
where p.home_phone = '123456789'
```